# How to use CASE/WHEN to categorise ranged values in SQL? If not possible, any alternatives?

Tags: sql, oracle, range, if-statement, case-when

Basically I want to be able to categorize the column selected into different range like so:
if the range > than 0 return the value of the column.
if the range < than 0 return 'Expired'.
Here is the code:

```
 SELECT 
    PACKAGE_ID,
    PACKAGE_NAME,
    ORG_ID, 
    ORG_NAME, 
    VALID_FROM,
    VALID_TO,
    DAYS_LEFT,
    TOTAL, 
    BALANCE,
    THRESHOLD,
    REPORTID 

 FROM
( SELECT  
    B.ORG_ID, 
    B.ORG_NAME, 
    A.PACKAGE_ID,
    A.NAME AS PACKAGE_NAME,
    A.BALANCE AS BALANCE,
    A.VALID_FROM,
    A.VALID_TO,
    C.REPORT_CODE,
     Floor(A.VALID_TO - (SELECT current_date FROM dual))  AS DAYS_LEFT, 
    X.TOTAL AS TOTAL, 
    CASE X.TOTAL  WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE A.BALANCE / X.TOTAL* 100  END AS THRESHOLD,    
    'MIS0014' AS REPORTID

    FROM 
    PREPAID_PACKAGE A 
        JOIN MST_ORGANISATION B ON B.ORG_ID = A.ORG_ID
            JOIN PREPAID_REPORT C  ON C.PACKAGE_ID = A.PACKAGE_ID
                    JOIN (
                       SELECT
                       SUM(Z.TOPUP_VALUE) as TOTAL,                       
                        Y.ORG_ID AS ORG_ID, 
                        Y.PACKAGE_ID AS PACKAGE_ID
                        from PREPAID_VALUE Z 
                            JOIN PREPAID_PACKAGE Y on  Y.PACKAGE_ID =Z.PACKAGE_ID
                            GROUP BY Y.ORG_ID, Y.PACKAGE_ID
                            )  X ON X.ORG_ID=A.ORG_ID AND X.PACKAGE_ID=A.PACKAGE_ID

   ORDER BY 
    ORG_CODE, 
    PACKAGE_ID,
    PACKAGE_NAME,
    C.REPORT_CODE)  S 

   WHERE
    REPORTID='MIS0014'
    AND ORG_ID = 1
    AND VALID_FROM >= TO_DATE('01/02/2007', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
    AND VALID_TO < TO_DATE('01/02/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
    AND THRESHOLD < 20
    AND DAYS_LEFT < 13

   GROUP BY
    PACKAGE_ID,
    PACKAGE_NAME,
    ORG_ID, 
    ORG_NAME, 
    DAYS_LEFT,
    VALID_FROM,
    VALID_TO,
    REPORTID,
    TOTAL,
    BALANCE,
    THRESHOLD,
    REPORTID
```

I'd like to change the following statement :

```
Floor(A.VALID_TO - (SELECT current_date FROM dual))  AS DAYS_LEFT,
```

to the following:

```
when Floor(A.VALID_TO - (SELECT current_date FROM dual)) > 0 then Floor(A.VALID_TO - (SELECT current_date FROM dual)) else 'Expired' end AS DAYS_LEFT,
```

or something similar, 
Is there any keyword/function to allow me to do it?

Comment: Are you allowed to write/add a user function to the DB and use it in your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've already got an inline query why not just do it in your main SELECT.

e.g.

```
SELECT 
    PACKAGE_ID,
    PACKAGE_NAME,
    ORG_ID, 
    ORG_NAME, 
    VALID_FROM,
    VALID_TO,
    TOTAL, 
    BALANCE,
    THRESHOLD,
    REPORTID,

   CASE 
       WHEN DAYS_LEFT > 0 THEN DAYS_LEFT -- Convert it to a Character of course
       ELSE 'Expired' 
   END as DAYS_LEFT
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have it almost correct already... but here's the correct syntax:

```
CASE WHEN FLOOR(A.VALID_TO - SYSDATE) > 0 
THEN FLOOR(A.VALID_TO - SYSDATE) 
ELSE 'Expired' 
END AS DAYS_LEFT,
```

In case Oracle complains you about not matching datatypes, it may mean that you need to cast the `FLOOR(A.VALID_TO - SYSDATE)` to `varchar2` by wrapping it inside a `CAST` function: `CAST(FLOOR(A.VALID_TO - SYSDATE) AS VARCHAR2(5))` - but that may not be necessary at all.

Comment: CASE 
       WHEN DAYS_LEFT > 0 THEN TO_CHAR(DAYS_LEFT)
       ELSE 'Expired' 
   END as DAYS_LEFT,
was sufficient for me :) cheers